# redirecting many websites to a domain marketplace

Tags: seo, google-search, 301-redirect

I'm building a small domain marketplace where I and a few friends want to sell a few of domain names.
We plan to redirect (301?) each domain to a dedicated page in the marketplace website.

we wonder if google may interpret this as a malicious way to improve pagerank. is there a risk we get penalized or banned for that ?

What happen if we get bigger and gather thousands of domains redirections ?

Comment: Pagerank, no longer exists in the form it once did, redirecting naked domains to other domains no longer pass the rankings they once did. I recommend that you read SEO guides written in the last decade, ideally in the last few years.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks for your help.  Just in case it wasn't clear : We don't redirect the domains in order to get more pagerank, but in order to have a nice 'parking' page for each of them. That said, can you give me a link to some documentation? do you know the answer to my 2 questions ?

Comment: Nothing will happen, thousands of registrars do it, with millions of domains. If your concerned then use `302 found` or a `307 Moved Temporarily` which should pass no relevancy, or juice.

Comment: do you mean no penalty can be passed through a 301 redirect?

Comment: Penalties do pass through 301, but naked domains do not pass anything, because they won't be indexed. But 302 and 307 do not, since no ranking is passed, while 301 normally does, but not shouldn't do on a naked domain. Only sites that are indexed can pass rankings.

Comment: just to make sure: what you call '301 redirect' on a 'naked domain' is when I make a 301 redirect on the domain, without path forwarding, for example : https://www.namesilo.com/Support/Domain-Forwarding. correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that is against Google Guidelines to use 301's for any other reason than moving your site to a new address, or consolidating several pages into one within the same website.

Technically is possible to do thousands of 301's is the purpose is to transfer authority to a "new" domain as long as you don't do a chain of 301s

However, I will not recommend doing that. The 301 is a http status for permanent move, and that is how is going to be interpreted  by search engines. This is not the message you would like to send to search engines even if you are planning to sell them later.

I will suggest to either Park the domain or redirect by 302's http status code (temporarily moved)

Comment: can you provide a link showing that it is "against Google Guidelines" to use 301 redirect in this case?

Comment: @Mark I am not saying this is a case against 301 google guidelines, I am just trying to point out that this is not the way google expect you to use 301s. It will be unnatural and risky. If you are planning to rank that marketplace page or domain, I will be really careful, you could potentially become penalized.

Answer (score 0):

I have used similar tactic to get more page rank. But google undertands 301 redirections and it is indexing only main website. Moreover, it is not illegal for google but no positive effect on page rank : [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=tr)

Comment: I'm a little confused : you say you used 'imilar tactic to get more page rank' but that it has 'no positive effect on page rank'. Do you mean when a domain is 301-redirected it won't pass any kind of "pagerank" ?

Comment: I thought I can trick google and  it will be useful to increase page rank. After a few months I have analyzed datas by using google webmaster tools and seen that it is not affecting rank (as explained by google at the link I provide)